# Efficiency in capturing groups (?: => work(?:\s+)?group VERSUS work(\s+)?group

Tags: javascript, regex, regex-group, capturing-group

Both expressions work for me:

```
E1=> work(?:\s+)?group 

E2=> work(\s+)?group
```

I need to capture `workgroup` OR `work group` considering the space could be a line break (\s+)?

However, the first expression has a non-capture groups (`?:` and I am wondering if it is worse or better in the performance/fast output of the Regex. In other words, in terms of performance, what is the best expression?

Comment: Why don't you use `\s*` ?

Comment: Whenever the question is _would a be faster than b or b faster than a_, the best solution is to just setup a little benchmark for yourself. The non-capturing group may be the tiniest bit immeasurably less memory-intensive, but `\s*` is a better solution to both as already suggested.

Comment: A non-capturing group will take longer for the regex parser/lexer, but will execute faster because of not having to store capturings.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski: "tiniest bit immeasurably less memory-intensive": in the current example probably, but in general it depends the size of the capture

Comment: Thanks guys. Learning a lot from you. I'm using \s* now. Considering a real expression I need to choose from two being the (?: the difference, what would you choose based in Regex efficiency/performance. My database has 6700 indexed PDF with 2,108,964 words. Exp1=> WORD1(?:\s+\w+){0,2}\s*\bdefin(es?|ed|itions?|ing)\b    /     Exp2=> WORD1(\s+\w+){0,2}\s*\bdefin(es?|ed|itions?|ing)\b   Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer actually depends on the internals of the regex engine you are using.

In Javascript, I don't know which is faster.

In PHP, a capture group can be a bit faster. Here is a simple test with a simplified version of your regex.

```
<?php
$string = "WORD1".str_repeat(" someword",100000);
$regex1="~WORD1(?:\s+\w+){0,2}~";
$regex2="~WORD1(\s+\w+){0,2}~";

$start=microtime(TRUE);
for ($i=1;$i<1000000;$i++) preg_match($regex1,$string);
$noncapend=microtime(TRUE);
for ($i=1;$i<1000000;$i++) preg_match($regex2,$string);
$withcapend=microtime(TRUE);
$noncap = $noncapend-$start;
$withcap = $withcapend-$noncapend;
$diff = 100*($withcap-$noncap)/$noncap;
echo "Non-Capture Group: ".$noncap."<br />";
echo "Capture Group: ".$withcap."<br />";
echo "difference: ".$diff." percent longer<br />";

?>
```

The Output:

Note that you will get different results every time.

```
Non-Capture Group: 1.092001914978
Capture Group: 1.0608019828796
difference: -2.857131628658 percent longer
```

Comment: Hey there, are you still wrestling with your question, or is it solved? Btw, I notice that you haven't yet voted on StackOverflow. If this answer or another answer solves your problem, please consider "accepting it" by clicking the checkmark and arrow on the left, as this is how the reputation system works. Of course there is no obligation to do so. Later when you have more reputation you can also upvote questions. Thanks for listening to my 20-second SO tutorial. :)